# Find best minima for initial conditions for past solution to match present values known

Tags: python, ode, solver, minimization, scipy-optimize-minimize

I have in Python an ODE system to solve and it is splitted in 2 parts : a past time solution and a future time solution :

Here is the ODE system :

```
# defining system
def sys_to_solve(t, funcs):
    return [
        funcs[0] * funcs[1],
        (
            3
            / (3 + 2 * omega_BD)
            * psi_x
            / funcs[0]
            * H0 ** 2
            * Omega_m
            * funcs[2] ** -3
            - (funcs[1]) ** 2
            - 3 * H(funcs[2], funcs[1], funcs[0]) * funcs[1]
        ),
        funcs[2] * H(funcs[2], funcs[1], funcs[0]),
    ]
```

I know present value (at t_now=0) of the 3 variables.

I am looking for finding initial values ( t=t_begin ) that will match, once solved, the present values.

The known values of present time are `x_0, x_1, x_2`

Here is the past solution implementation :

```
sol_past = solve_ivp(
        sys_to_solve,
        [t_begin, t_now],
        [z1, z2 , z3],
        method="RK45",
        t_eval=t_past,
        rtol=1e-12,
        )
```

To find these initial values, someone told me, to find appropriate `z1,z2,z3` above, the following method :

```
def objective(x):
    sol_past = solve_ivp(
        sys_to_solve,
        [t_begin, t_now],
        [x[0], x[1], x[2]],
        method="RK45",
        t_eval=t_past,
        rtol=1e-12,
    )
    y1 = sol_past.y[0,:]
    y2 = sol_past.y[1,:]
    y3 = sol_past.y[2,:]

    return np.abs(y1[-1] - x_0), np.abs(y2[-1] - x_1), np.abs(y3[-1] - x_2)

z1,z2,z3 = fsolve(objective, [6.45, 1.317, 0.3] , xtol=1e-12)
```

But the values `6.45, 1.317 and 0.3` have been found by random or step by step methods.

Now, I would like to justify and find these values with a numerical method well established, and not just a pseudo-random fine-tuning.

I have heard this method is called the "shooting method".

I think about minimizers methods like the minimization of a Chi2 : Could anyone help me how to proceed to find similar values `6.45, 1.317 and 0.3` that will match the best the present values `x_0,x_1,x_3` ?

**EDIT** : the solution given by @Lutz Lehmann works well on the 2 first parameters ( Psi = G * phi and F0 = d_Phi_0 / dt / Phi0 ) but I have not much a good math for the scale factor H(t) = da/dt / a given the fact that I have only access to a(t) and not da/dt /a.

Here the bad match on H(t) :

[Bad match witht expected H(z) in blue point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vgBO.png)

However, I get consistent curves for the curve of scale factor and `Psi(t)` and `F0 = d_Phi_0 / Phi0`

[Well match with a(t](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFRiA.png)

For information, we get funcs[0] = Psi(t), funcs[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vgBO.png)=F(t) and funcs[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFRiA.png)=a(t)

So surely, the shooting method could solve this issue on H(t) with currently too high values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format is always that the time span is given as `[t0,tf]` for with initial point `y0` for the condition `y(t0)=y0` and integration to the time `tf`.

It makes no difference for the solver if `tf > t0` or `tf < t0`. If given, the `t_eval` array has to be ordered appropriately. So you only need to change the call to

```
sol_past = solve_ivp(
        sys_to_solve,
        [t_now, t_begin],
        [z1, z2 , z3],
        method="RK45",
        t_eval=t_past,
        rtol=1e-12,
        )
```